# getline() function error in c++ code

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here i am getting an error saying getline() not declared in this scope.........any help would be appreciated.

no matching function for call to getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*&)

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;

    char *s;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE* fd = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if(fd == NULL)
        {
            fputs("Unable to open input.txt\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        size_t length = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        const char* backup;

        while ((read = getline(&s, &length, fd) ) > 0)
        {
            backup = s;
            if (A() && *s == '\n')
            {
                printf("%sis in the language\n", backup);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%sis not in the language\n", backup);
            }
        }
        fclose(fd);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `s` is declared... where? And `getline` doesn't declare itself. Include your `#include` list with your code. I assume you're trying to use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) from the POSIX libs, is that correct?

Comment: folks i just edited my post as i was expecting you to ask me that

Comment: `getline` from POSIX is in `stdio.h`, which you're not including (or the C++ equivalent, `cstdio`). And you may-well have to declare _POSIX_C_SOURCE with the appropriate version value to pull its declaration in (`200809L` or later).

Comment: @WhozCraig it's still not working with #include <cstdio>

Comment: What is your while loop supposed to do?

Comment: @JonAbraham are you trying to use the standard C++ `std::getline` or the posix `getline`? They got different function signatures. Also you might run into problems due to your `using namespace std`  if you include headers for both.

Comment: @DevangJayachandran while loop is suppose to read a text file and then parse that each line when it comes to 'if' condition.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl i am trying to use std::getline

Comment: @Jon Abraham that i know of at least, std::getline doesn't read files. Here are the parameters: `istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim)`, that is why the error says there isn't a function that matches the given argument types

Comment: You defined that feature macro **before** the include file list, *right* ? As in, [something like this](http://ideone.com/W07Jls). If you want to use the POSIX C library function, that is how you do it. If you want to use the standard C++ library's `std::getline`, then [see the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), because you're not even close. They're different functions.

Comment: @JonAbraham first check if you have POSIX getline available: make a new program that only has `#include <stdio.h>`  and try to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use C++ style code in order to use getline in a cross platform way.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::string s;

bool A() { return true; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if(!myfile.is_open())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t length = 0;
    size_t read;
    std::string backup;

    while (getline(myfile, s))
    {
        backup = s;
        if (A() && s == "\n")
        {
            printf("%s is in the language\n", backup.c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s is not in the language\n", backup.c_str());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ah, looks like the stdio.h version of getline is a GNU extension and you must be using another compiler (MSVC?). You'll need to adopt your code to use the C++ version of getline and std::string.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused with various `getline` function signatures.

The standard C++ [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) signature is

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input,
                                           std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                                           CharT delim );
```

It takes an input stream object, a string and a character delimiter (there's an overload without the delimiter too).

The posix [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) signature is

```
ssize_t getdelim(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim, FILE *stream);
```

with the delimiter optional again.

now in your code your passing arguments as if calling the posix version without delimiter. If you want to use the standard one you'll have to change the arguments (i.e. `istream` object instead of `FILE*`). I don't know if the posix one is even available for you, since posix is different from any C++ standard.

Note that the `fputs`, `FILE*`, `fprintf` are C filehandling functions, not the C++ ones.

Comment: I will rectify the code to make it more simpler. I will go with std::getline

Comment: @JonAbraham also if you have trouble with I/O you might want to go over a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). I don't know how you somehow ended up finding the C functions instead of the C++ though.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with `getline(&s, &length, fd)`? Are you trying to use the C `getline`?

Assuming you have opened the file correctly, in c++ your `getline` should look something like this: `getline(inputStream, variableToReadInto, optionalDelimiter)`.

- You didn't include `<stdio.h>` but you did include `<fstream>`. Maybe use `ifstream fd("input.txt");`
- What's `A()`
- If you ARE trying to use the C `getline`, the `using namespace std` may be interfering
- Why are you using `printf` and `fprintf` and not `cout << xxxxxx` and `fd << xxxxxx`

Comment: @ i m learning the hard way i guess. I will fix the code according to recommendations.

Comment: Are you migrating from C?

Comment: Then who taught you to write this C-style code in C++ programs?